# I need to clean up and split words from a mess of data into their own cells in a row. How can I accomplish this?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to create documentation from an export of data that gives me a jumbled mess all in one cell that I need to clean up and extract certain bits from.

Here is an example:

```
[{"label":"Native Invoice","value":"native_invoice","displayOrder":0,"hidden":false,"readOnly":false},{"label":"Data Sync","value":"data_sync","displayOrder":1,"hidden":false,"readOnly":false}]
```

All of this is in one cell, and I need to have only the following information in their own individual rows:

```
Native Invoice

Data Sync
```

This example only has 2 values, but some that I am working on have hundreds, and it is taking far too long to manually copy and paste the values I need into their own cells.

Note: I am working in Google Sheets exclusively.

Comment: This might be done using built-in formulas and Google Apps Script. Please make the question more specific by telling us directly in the question what you have tried and adding a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse a cell contain stringified JSON. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040127/parse-json-from-google-spreadsheet-cell

Comment: Alternatively, find an online utility to `convert JSON to CSV` (literally search that in Google), and you can manually paste your cell value and get a neatly delimited list in the output. It's a manual way to get the results-- one Google Sheets cell at a time-- but a lot less manual than what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how a custom function can look like:

```
function parse(txt) {
  var jsn = JSON.parse(txt);
  return [jsn[0].label, jsn[1].label];
}
```

Here is how it works:

[image]

You put the data into cell A1, put the formula `=parse(A1)` into the cell B1, and get the results in cells B1 and B2.

**Update**

If you want to get labels from all objects of the data, here is another variant of the function:

```
function get_labels(txt) {
  return JSON.parse(txt).map(x => x.label); // get 'label' from all the objects
}
```

It works about the same way:

[image]

Comment: Hi Yuri, thank you for this! I do believe it is exactly what I need. 

That said, I notice I need to duplicate jsn[1].label for each option, and again, some of the fields I am copying have hundreds of values. Is there a way to capture a large range without having to copy and paste jsn[1].label each time with the number updated?

I appreciate your help so much! I am venturing into very new territory and your support is so valuable!

Comment: In your example I see the array that contains two objects. Each object has some properties. The property `label`, etc. So, what do you need? The rest properties in the objects? Or there can be more objects and you need to get the `label` property each of the objects?

Comment: I just added the variant of the code to get `label` property from all objects of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to pull anything after `"label":` without quotes. If that's the case, and if you are open to a formula instead of a script, supposing that your raw-data block were in A1, place this in B1:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(FLATTEN(REGEXREPLACE(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"label.:.([^"&CHAR(34)&"]+)","~|$1~"),"~"),"\|")),,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"label.:.([^"&CHAR(34)&"]+)","~|$1~"),"~")),"\|","")),"WHERE Col1 Is Not Null")))`